# Google Map API get address information by postal code, but it response result by street number

Tags: google-maps-api-3, compass-geolocation

I am using google map api to get address information by Postal code around the world [ not specific country].

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=610&key=[apiKey]

I expected zip code is 610, but google response result for street number 610.

Is there any ways to get address by zip code only?

Thank you guys in advance for supporting.

Comment: "610" is not an address. First sentence of the documentation: *Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like a street address) into geographic coordinates.*

Comment: Thank MrUpsidown, Is it possible to make Geocoding convert "610" to zipcode not street number?

Comment: In how many countries do you think a zip code like "610" would exist? "610" is **not** an address and the service you are using is for converting addresses. If you want to toast bread, use a toaster.

Comment: MrUpsidown, this is just an example of zip code. I mean user can input any zip code belong to their country. I used google api to get information by Zip code only.

Answer (score 3):

How about something along with this query

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:1441|country:PH&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This will get you the address kind of this format
http://prntscr.com/ouwlq5

Key note here is the country. You need both of the postal_code and the country to make this work. Without country you'll get zero results.

Comment: Thank Keysl, But I don't know the country because my application support all country zipcode.

Comment: I'm afraid this is quite impossible to do, each country has its own zip/postal code format and sometimes they overlap to other countries, hence google maps api requires country if you use postal code as criterion

Comment: Just re-think your use case. You need **at least** the zip code and the country.

Comment: Maybe you can work around it if you detect the country of your client using geolocation. So country code can be filled automatically behind the ui. For example at the page load get the current cpuntry using google geolocation api and then fill it on your maps api or something like that. Its not doable directly but with few additional steps can make it work